# Only serialize a single object with ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

In my project I have a model DrinkPayment:

```
class DrinkPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Association
  belongs_to :drink
  belongs_to :participation
end
```

And my Serializer for this model:

```
class DrinkPaymentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ActiveModel::Serializer.setup do |config|
    config.embed = :ids
    config.embed_in_root = true
  end

  attributes :id, :participation_id, :drink_id

  has_one :participation
  has_one :drink
end
```

Doing it like this gives me all DrinkPayments (id, participation_id, drink_id), all Participations(id, user_id,...) and all Drinks(id, club_id, ...). The problem I have is that I do not need the Participations, I just want the DrinkPayments and the respective drinks. Or even better just the drinks.

Is there a possibility to achieve this with ActiveModel::Serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `DrinkPaymentSerializer` to reflect what you need:

```
class DrinkPaymentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

  has_one :drink
end
```

You can add anything you want to the serializer:

```
class DrinkPaymentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :drink_name, :price

  def drink_name
    object.drink.name
  end

  def price
    { amount: object.amount, currency: object.currency }
  end
end
```